# Python - sum of two numbers program error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just getting into Python programming. I wrote a simple program to calculate sum of two user-input numbers:

```
a,b = input("enter first number"), input("enter second number")
print("sum of given numbers is ", (a+b))
```

Now if I enter the numbers as 23 and 52, what showed in the output is:

```
sum of given numbers is  23 52
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to convert them to integers first, then do the calculation. Right now they're being treated as strings. http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input

Comment: convert strings to int first

Comment: Probably not the best use of the unpacking notation, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input()` in Python 3 returns a string; you need to convert the input values to integers with `int()` before you can add them:

```
a,b = int(input("enter first number")), int(input("enter second number"))
```

(You may want to wrap this in a `try:`/`except ValueError:` for nicer response when the user doesn't enter an integer.

Comment: This worked too, but I feel this a bit difficult... But thanks for introducing me to this method... :) <3

Answer (score 4):

instead of `(a+b)`, use `(int(a) + int(b)`)

Comment: Thanks!! This was easier than adding datatype while initializing itself (for me)... :) A thousan thanks!!! <3

Comment: My Pleasure :) This has the added benefit of keeping your original strings a and b intact, which might be useful later in your program.

Answer (score 4):

I think it will be better if you use a try/except block, since you're trying to convert strings to integers

```
try:
    a,b = int(input("enter first number")), int(input("enter second number"))
    print("sum of given numbers is ", (a+b))
except ValueError as err:
    print("You did not enter numbers")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default python takes the input as string. So instead of adding both the numbers string concatenation is occurring in your code. So you should explicitly convert it into integer using the int() method.
Here is a sample code

```
a,b=int(input("Enter the first number: ")),int(input("Enter the second number: "))
print("Sum of the numbers is ", a + b)
```

For more information check this link
https://codingwithwakil.blogspot.com/2021/05/python-program-to-add-two-numbers-by.html